# Find line with digits

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing

How to find a line that contains numerical values?

i.e. I want to find some line that has some digits in it. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 . Can I do this with the `grep` command ?

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can!

```
grep '[0-9]' file
```

Replace `file` with the name of your file...

Comment: An alternative version using the locale-independent class is `grep '[[:digit:]]' file`.

Answer (score 12):

Here are a few choices, all using the following test input file:

```
foo
bar 12
baz
```

All of these commands will print any input lines containing at least one number:

```
$ grep '[0-9]' file
bar 12
$ grep -P '\d' file
bar 12
$ awk '/[0-9]/' file
bar 12
$ sed -n '/[0-9]/p' file
bar 12
$ perl -ne 'print if /\d/' file
bar 12
$ while read line; do [[ $line =~ [0-9] ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"; done < file
bar 12
$ while read line; do [[ $line = *[0-9]* ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"; done < file
bar 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentioned python yet, so here it is:

```
bash-4.3$ cat file
foo
foo1bar
barfoo foo bar
barfoo 123 foobar 321
bash-4.3$ python -c 'import re,sys;matched=[line.strip() for line in sys.stdin if re.findall("[0-9]",line)];print "\n".join(matched)' < file 
foo1bar
barfoo 123 foobar 321
```

Basic idea how this works is that we give file as stdin input, python code reads all lines in stdin and uses `re.findall()` function from the regex module to match lines, and finally prints out the list of those lines. A bit lengthy , but works. Some parts can be shortened a lot, say like this:

```
python -c 'import re,sys;print "\n".join([l.strip() for l in sys.stdin if re.findall("[0-9]",l)])' < file
```

On side note, this is python2. Use `print` function with parentheses to adapt it to python3

Comment: Python 2 supports `print()` with parentheses too, just add them and the code will (probably) work on both Py2 and Py3.

Comment: @gronostaj  Yep, python 2 does allow `print()`  although the behavior of python 3  is different in a lot of respects.In this case it will work, but there's a lot of other cases where it won't. I'll keep my answer the way it is. People should be aware that python 2 and 3 are somewhat different.

Comment: My answer was downvoted. Why ?